# A closed set in $\mathbb A^2_k\times\mathbb P^1_k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and consider the Zariski topology on $\mathbb A^2_k$ and on $\mathbb P^1_k$.

If

$$X:=\left\{((x_0,x_1),(y_0:y_1))\in\mathbb A^2_k\times \mathbb P^1_k\,\bigg| x_0y_1=x_1y_0\,\right\}\subseteq \mathbb A^2_k\times \mathbb P^1_k$$

I don't understand why $X$ is closed in $\mathbb A^2_k\times \mathbb P^1_k$.

The structure of variety on $\mathbb A^2_k\times \mathbb P^1_k$ is obtained by patching of the affine varieties $\{\mathbb A^2\times U_i\}_{i=0,1}$ where $U_1=\{(x_0:1)\,:x_0\in k\}$ and $U_0=\{(1:x_1)\,:x_1\in k\}$. Now is there some kind of "characterization" for closed sets of $\mathbb A^2_k\times \mathbb P^1_k$?

Comment: Closed sets of $\mathbb A_k^2 \times \mathbb P_k^1$ correspond to polynomials in four variables, that are homogeneous in two of them.

Comment: You seem to be answering your own question to some extent. You've given an open cover of $\mathbf{A}^2 \times \mathbf{P}^1$ by affine varieties, which gives a straightforward way to check that your set $X$ is closed: just check that its intersection with each of the sets of the open cover is closed. Working out the details leads to Fredrik Meyer's characterisation of closed sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a characterization of closed subsets of $\mathbb A^2_k\times \mathbb P^1_k$.

Namely, they are the common zeros of a family $(f_i(x_0,x_1;y_o,y_1))_{i\in I}$ of polynomials $f_i(x_0,x_1;y_o,y_1)$, required to be homogeneous in the variables $y_0,y_1$ associated to $\mathbb P^1_k$.
The degree of homogeneity of these polynomials may vary with $i\in I$.
Your example is a little confusing (by no fault of yours!) because the polynomial $x_0y_1-x_1y_0$ happens to be homogeneous (of degree $1$) also in the variables $x_0,x_1$ of $\mathbb A^2_k$, which is absolutely not required in general.
This means that your subvariety $X\subset \mathbb A^2_k\times \mathbb P^1_k$ descends to a subvariety $\mathbb P(X)\subset \mathbb P^1_k \times \mathbb P^1_k$.

**A geometric interpretation**
You have the Plücker embedding $$p:\mathbb P^1_k \times \mathbb P^1_k\hookrightarrow \mathbb P^3_k: ((x_0:x_1),(y_0:y_1))\mapsto (z_0:z_1:z_2:z_3)=(x_0y_0:x_0y_1:x_1y_0:x_1y_1)$$The image $p(\mathbb P(X))\subset \mathbb P^3_k$ of $\mathbb P(X)$ under that embedding is then the intersection of the quadric $z_0z_3-z_1z_2=0$ with the plane $z_1-z_2=0$.
 In other words, a good old projective conic!

Comment: I hadn't seen Fredrik's  comment  when I started to write this post. Consider this answer as  just a development of his perfect, crisp explanation, which I'm upvoting right now.